# Long running task with healthchecks

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, fastapi

I'm currently implementing a containerized python app to process messages from a queue.

The main process would poll the queue every n seconds and then process all the messages it receives. However, I would also like this app to expose an API with healthchecks and other endpoints that could send jobs to the main process.

I was wondering what are the standard libraries to do this in python, if they exist. I have seen some examples using Background tasks on FastAPI but this would not meet my requirements as the service should poll the queue on startup without any request to its endpoints.

I have also seen the Celery library mentioned, but it seems like large complexity leap from what I need.

Is there a simple way to run a FastAPI application 'side-by-side'  with a long running process in a way that both can communicate?

Answer (score 0):

the multiprocessing module has its own version of queues.  In your calling program, first create a queue, like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
self.outq_log=mp.Queue()
```

then pass this Queue object to the process by putting it in the arguments when you call mp.Process() to start your long running task.

then a function in your calling program to check for messages in the queue would look like:

```
def service_queues(self):
  #look for data from the process, print it in the windows
  try:
    if self.outq_log is not None:
      x=self.outq_log.get(block=False)
      self.logtxt.write(x)
  except queue.Empty:
    pass
```

finally, in your long running process you can send items to the caller using

```
outq_log.put(stuff)
```

If you want to send messages the other way, to the task from the caller, you can create a separate queue and do the "put"ting in the caller and the "get"ting in the task.

Answer (score -1):

You can run FastAPI programatically like in [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/debugging/#call-uvicorn) example, after starting your other tasks in a thread or using asyncio. This way you should be able to communicate from the server endpoints to whatever objects you've started before.